# CheckBox OnCheckedChangeListener() called after recycled?

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

## Problem

I created a custom expandablelistadapter to handle my checkboxes correctly when a childrow is clicked. I added a OnCheckedChangeListener to the checkbox and passed the item I wanted to operate on as a tag. Weird things start to happen when the view I was clicking on got recycled(I beleive). I expand a parent, then mark my child, this works fine, and then when I collapse the parent and expand another parent the OnCheckedChangeListener for the child I clicked earlier is fired. This isnt really consistant, sometimes it works good but sometimes not.

## Question

What is making my checkboxes change state and how can I avoid it?
It works fine exept these "random" changes of state.

## Very simplified code

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.site_picker_list_item_child1, null);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.site_test_child_selected);

    final ObjectA obj = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    checkbox.setTag(obj);
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkbox, boolean isChecked) {

            ((ObjectA)checkbox.getTag()).selected = isChecked;

            if (isChecked)
                Log.d(TAG, "CHECKED: " + ((ObjectA)checkbox.getTag()).name);
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "UNCHECKED: " + ((ObjectA)checkbox.getTag()).name);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public class ObjectA {
    String name = "Hello";
    Boolean selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be removing the listener before setting checked, for example:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
checkBox.setChecked(obj.checked);
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need keep checked state in your ObjectA class

For example

```
class ObjectA{
    boolean checked;
}
```

in getView method

```
  final ObjectA obj = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkbox, boolean isChecked){
                obj.checked = isChecked;
            }

        });

  checkBox.setChecked(obj.checked);
```

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't show in my example that I had tried that, but it doesnt work either, because the checkbox gets unchecked quite random and that makes the object.checked get checked too.. so next time I expand that parent(group) again it is unchecked... I think its a really weird behavior... any other thoughts of solution?

Comment: I've added code to not make any other confused about the same thing.

Comment: This approach works for me, try to avoid tag and use obj directly. Here is my example https://github.com/gobozov/myshows/blob/master/src/ru/myshows/fragments/NewEpisodesFragment.java

Comment: So, rather finalize viewholder and the object than just using a static viewholder class? (I use static viewholder now and save groupPosition/childPosition, then look up my "obj" in the OnCheckedChangedListener by using the group/child- positions. Isn't finalizing the object too grabbing more memory unnecessarily? Cuz my lookup for the object doesn't take that much time really(not using asynctask atm).